# Vectorised method to append dataframe rows to columns and vice-versa

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

My dataframe is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': {'d': 1, 'e': 0, 'f': 1, 'g': 1},
                   'b': {'d': 0, 'e': 0, 'f': 0, 'g': 1},
                   'c': {'d': 0, 'e': 1, 'f': 1, 'g': 0}})
```

which gives:

```
>>> df
   a  b  c
d  1  0  0
e  0  0  1
f  1  0  1
g  1  1  0
```

For every row in the dataframe, I would like to add a new column of `0`s , and for every column in the dataframe, I would like to add a new row of `0`s.

I've attempted to solve this problem so far in the following way:

```
edges = df.columns

for i in df.index:
    df[i] = [0 for _ in range(len(df.index))]

for e in edges:
    df = df.append(pd.Series({c:0 for c in df.columns},name=e))
```

Which results in the desired output:

```
>>> df
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g
d  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
e  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
f  1  0  1  0  0  0  0
g  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
a  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
b  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
c  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Is there a vectorised alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) witn `columns` and `index` parameter, new values should be created by [`Index.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.append.html):

```
df1 = df.reindex(columns=df.columns.append(df.index), 
                 index=df.index.append(df.columns), 
                 fill_value = 0)
print (df1)
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g
d  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
e  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
f  1  0  1  0  0  0  0
g  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
a  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
b  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
c  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Or by [`Index.union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html):

```
df1 = df.reindex(columns=df.columns.union(df.index, sort=False), 
                 index=df.index.union(df.columns, sort=False), 
                 fill_value = 0)
print (df1)
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g
a  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
b  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
c  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
d  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
e  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
f  1  0  1  0  0  0  0
g  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way using [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
(df.reindex(df.columns.append(df.index), 
           axis=1, 
           fill_value =0)
  .reindex(df.index.append(df.columns), 
           axis=0, 
           fill_value =0))
```

---

```
print(df_new)

   a  b  c  d  e  f  g
d  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
e  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
f  1  0  1  0  0  0  0
g  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
a  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
b  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
c  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a dictionary from `fromkeys` then unpack it, then use `assign` and `T` then `assign` then `T`:

```
print(df.assign(**dict.fromkeys(df.index, 0)).T.assign(**dict.fromkeys(df.columns, 0)).T)
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g
d  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
e  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
f  1  0  1  0  0  0  0
g  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
a  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
b  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
c  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```