# Pandas read_csv gives decimal column numbers

Tags: python, pandas, csv, bipartite

I've been pulling my hair out trying to make a bipartite graph from a csv file and so far all I have is a panda matrix that looks like this
[image]

My code so far is just

```
`
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# import pyexcel as pe
# import pyexcel.ext.xlsx
from networkx.algorithms import bipartite

mat = pd.read_csv("networkdata3.csv")
# mat = pd.read_excel("networkdata1.xlsx",sheet_name="sheet_name_1")
print(mat.info)
sand = nx.from_pandas_adjacency(mat)
```

`

and I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. Initially I was trying to read it in as the original xlsx file but then I just converted it to a csv and it started reading. I assume I can't make the graph because the column numbers are decimals and the error that spits out claims that the column numbers don't match up. So how else should I be doing this to actually start making some progress?

Comment: Without access to your data it is hard to tell what is going on when reading either the xlsx or csv.  My first instinct would be to check if `len(mat.columns) == len(mat)`.  If this returns `True` then the adjacency matrix is square which is, of course, a good thing!   Though it could be incorrect, you could try assuming that whatever is causing columns to be renamed isn't reordering them.  Just set `mat.columns = mat.index` and you'll likely be able to build the graph.  Does that work?  If so, does your graph makes sense?

Comment: The length of the columns to rows does not match up on the csv unfortunately 
all of my data is fairly well represented by the image posted

Comment: Ah, so what you really have is a *biadjacency* matrix.  I think you'll find your solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59862598/importing-non-square-adjacency-matrix-into-networkx-python).   You'll have to be a little careful, however, because it looks like at least one of your rows and columns have the same name (i.e. `1`).  If you use the answer in the linked post that relies on generating the full adjacency matrix, I'd suggest renaming all rows and/or columns to avoid node name conflicts.